# How can I use PHP/Apache (mod_rewrite) to redirect URLs as hash tags?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

When a URL like `/songs/123` is directly hit, I want to rewrite/redirect that URL to `/index.php#/songs/123`.

I figure using the server to do this is more efficient than creating "dummy" pages that redirect.

For example, I use jQuery.address to 'catch' any `<a/>` tags and append its `href` as a hash tag, allowing the site to be navigated seamlessly and have browser history maintain accuracy. I still want these hrefs to be valid links to the appropriate content however in case someone opens it in a new tab or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (in your .htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/songs/(.+)$ /index.php#/songs/$1 [R,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Or a more extreme case that captures anything that isn't a file/directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php#$1 [R,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: will the latter affect my image,js,etc directories?

Comment: Try it out, but the two rewrite conditions say to NOT rewrite if the file exists or a directory exists. So if you create a directory calling it "songs" and then put a file called "123" into it, then the redirect will not happen. Try it out though and see how far you get.

Comment: N.B. The [`NE` (no escape)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flag is important here, otherwise the hash will get URL escaped to `%23`.

Answer (score 7):

Since the URL fragment only matters on the client, you need to force the client to redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^/songs/(.*) /index.php#/songs/$1 [R,L,NE]
```

Comment: +1 for the redirect note, I added it to my full htaccess example below

Comment: what is the significane of the [R, L]?