# htaccess mod rewrite - can I forward my URL to another URL with a hash tag?

Tags: .htaccess

A small but confusing htaccess problem here, on mod_rewrite. 
We need to forward:
    http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/?shoesize=43&calfwidth=K
to
    http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/#nogo&somevar=1&shoesize=43&calfwidth=K

Our code (thanks to another Stackoverflow post) is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shoesize=([0-9]+)\&calfwidth=([A-Z])$ 
RewriteRule ^ladies-boots/$ http://www.mydomain.com/ladies-boots/#nogo&somevar=1&shoesize=%1&calfwidth=%2? [R=301,L]
```

The above works great, except the hash # tag is escaped by Apache,  which writes the URL as with a %23 instead of the #.

Is there any way I can work around this? I do need the hash tag for some Javascript/non-SE-friendly functionality and the above URL is not usable without a working hash tag.

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use PHP/Apache (mod_rewrite) to redirect URLs as hash tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136642/how-can-i-use-php-apache-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-urls-as-hash-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above works great, except the hash # tag is escaped by Apache, which writes the URL as with a %23 instead of the #.

You can have the hash tag unescaped if you use the `NE` flag inside the square brackets: `[R=301,L,NE]`

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way. URLs can contain only letters, numbers and the symbols / ? &.